# How do I include the Extjs 5.1 features to the Eclipse?

Tags: extjs, eclipse-plugin

I am trying add Extjs plugin to eclipse. But it was not working. Can anyone help me how can I include Ext js features to eclipse.

Comment: when I trying to do the steps given in https://github.com/DIRACGrid/WebAppDIRAC/wiki/How-to-setup-Eclipse-for-developing-ExtJs, I am getting error after first step

Comment: What is the error message? Can you post a screenshot?